# Pointwise convergence of sequence of continuous functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

The very first example of pointwise convergence of continuous functions one meets is $f_n(x)=x^n$ with $x\in [0,1]$.

Here $f_n$'s are continuous on $[0,1]$, but their pointwise limit is not continuous at $1$.

**Q.** Is there an example of sequence $f_n$ of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that their pointwise limit is nowhere continuous?

Comment: I think the Dirichlet function would help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function

Comment: No, the limit function will be continuous on a dense $G_\delta$ subset of $[0,1]$ (which must be uncountable btw). This is a consequence of Baire's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1+\dfrac{x}{n}, \: x\in [0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\\0,\: \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Is $f_n$ continuous on whole $[0,1]$?

Comment: I didn't check that. I will get back to you. I will update the answer soon.

Comment: Obviously not by density of the rationals and irrationals